# Relative Url to Virtual Path?

Tags: c#, asp.net, virtual-path

I can find lots of .NET functions that convert a `virtual path ("~/images/test.jpeg")` to a `relative url ("/MYSITE/images/test.jpeg")`, however do any functions exist that convert a Relative Url to a Virtual path?

The alternative is to use something like:

```
var relativeUrl = "/MYSITE/css/reset.css";
var appPath = System.Web.HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppVirtualPath;

string virtualPath = string.Empty;
if (relativeUrl.IndexOf(appPath, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) == 0)
    virtualPath = relativeUrl.Substring(appPath.Length);
...
```

Instead.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
string pathFROM = Server.MapPath("~/MYSITE/css/reset.css");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to use it in asp.net:

```
string relativeUrl = "/MYSITE/css/reset.css";
string virtualpath= Server.MapPath("/")+relativeUrl.substring(1,relativeUrl.Length-1)
```